# How to report exceptions and UncaughtExcept with detail description to Google Analytics v4?

Tags: android, exception, google-analytics, acra, google-analytics-firebase

I know this question has been asked many times with different forms but didn't find any working and updated solution that works with GAv4.

So far I've followed these [link1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions) and [link2](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/googleanalyticshelloworld/MyApp.java), for tracking exception reports with some custom changes,

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    /**
     * The Analytics singleton. The field is set in onCreate method override
     * when the application class is initially created.
     */
    private static GoogleAnalytics analytics;

    /**
     * The default app tracker. The field is from onCreate callback when the
     * application is initially created.
     */
    private static Tracker tracker;

    /**
     * Access to the global Analytics singleton. If this method returns null you
     * forgot to either set android:name="&lt;this.class.name&gt;" attribute on
     * your application element in AndroidManifest.xml or you are not setting
     * this.analytics field in onCreate method override.
     */
    public static GoogleAnalytics analytics() {
        return analytics;
    }

    /**
     * The default app tracker. If this method returns null you forgot to either
     * set android:name="&lt;this.class.name&gt;" attribute on your application
     * element in AndroidManifest.xml or you are not setting this.tracker field
     * in onCreate method override.
     */
    public static Tracker tracker() {
        return tracker;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

        // TODO: Replace the tracker-id with your app one from
        // https://www.google.com/analytics/web/
        tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-**********");

        // Provide unhandled exceptions reports. Do that first after creating
        // the tracker
        tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);

        // Enable Remarketing, Demographics & Interests reports
        // https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/display-features
        tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);    
    }
}
```

In GAv4 "Description" has limit of 100 characters for sending exception, but some how I've successfully manage to extend that limit and send stackTrace as follows,

```
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

            // Get full error message from prinStrackTrace
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));

            String errorMessage = "em-" + extraMessage + "||pst-"
                    + errors.toString();
            Log.e(TAG, "errorMessage = " + errorMessage);
            MyApplication.tracker().send(
                    new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                            .setDescription(errorMessage).setFatal(false)
                            .build());
        }
    }
```

This is for catching exception, but now I want to send detail stacktrace crash report for uncaught exception. This [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions) has help to get uncaught exception but doesn't provide much detail in GA. I did find this [approach](http://dandar3.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/google-analytics-easytracker-detailed.html) but that is basically for GAv2.

Q1 : So is my above approach for sending stacktrace for caught exception will work with future GA or is there any another way to get detail description for exact cause of error, class name and line number?

Q2 : How to send full stacktrace or any exact helpful description to find reason of uncaught exception?

Q3 : I know about ACRA, but is there any free [backend](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets) to capture any additional information from the Exception object.

add:

```
.setCustomDimension(1, e.getMessage())
```

to your ExceptionBuilder code. Note you need to first create the custom dimension in web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Since no one know what a future version of GA will look like this question is unanswerable.

Q3: There are open source implementations of ACRA backends. Look at https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends. But you will need to organise hosting for them. Alternatively many of the commercial versions offer quite reasonable free quota and reasonable plans after that.